# Why Server restarts are improving Load balancing?

Tags: performance, jvm, load, load-balancing, f5

Load balancing is not proper in our application but it improves upon server restart. Why Load balancing improves if I restart JVMs ?

PS We are using f5 load balancer with 30 instances of JVMs in 5 servers

Comment: When you say load balancing "improves" what do you mean? Is the load shared more equally? 

What are you using to persist across the servers on the F5? Is it cookie persistance, src address?

Comment: yes load shares more equally.. to persist -we are using JSessionId

Answer (score 0):

isolate the server causing the behavior by disabling all except one server at a time in the pool this will give you more insight into the issue.